# How do i change the image in a "flip" animation in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

So I am trying to make an animation for a memory game project. The animation I am having trouble with is the flip animation. I have no problem making the image flip, but I want to make it change the image after the scale.x went from -1 to 0. This is what I have so far:

```
     <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="ImageButton">
        <Image Source="gurbe1.jpg"
               x:Name="image"
               Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />

    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ImageButton}"
            Width="100" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform" ScaleX="-1" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:1"  Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="1" BeginTime="0:0:1" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>



</Grid>
</Window>
```

I already looked on here and tried some stuff, but I couldn't get it to work :

[xaml change image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286714/xaml-change-image-source)

[How can I do multiple animations in a single storyboard in C#/XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293269/how-can-i-do-multiple-animations-in-a-single-storyboard-in-c-xaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people also having this problem, it's as  simple as this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform" ScaleX="-1" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe1.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:1"  Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="100" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="AnimatedScaleTransform2" ScaleX="0" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="gurbe2.jpg"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" BeginTime="0:0:2.3" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedScaleTransform2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>



</Grid>
```

It's not smooth atm, but you can get pretty close by adjusting the begin time